# IOS google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps

my IOS google maps application blue beam does not showing which direction I am facing(as attached screen showing)

please help to advise.

[image]

Comment: You can see a blue flash light sort of thing emerging from the blue icon right? that's the direction the user is actually facing. Try rotating your device and the flash light will keep changing its directions accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Setting > Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Compass Calibration > Enable

Answer (score 0):

You can see a blue flash light sort of thing emerging from the blue icon right? that's the direction the user is actually facing.
Try rotating your device and the flash light will keep changing its directions accordingly.

Comment: Hi Karthick, thanks for your reply. I am looking to enable " flash light of of thing " . is ok I have found it how to enable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know it's a bit late
Here is the solution:

Settings --> General --> Reset --> Reset Location & Privacy